# Proof about distances in banach spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $(X,\|\circ\|)$ be a banach space with

$$\forall x,y\in X, x\neq y, \|x\|=\|y\|=1 \Rightarrow \|\frac{x+y}{2}\|<1 $$

If M is convex and $z \in X$, then $\|x-z\|=dist(z,M)$ for at most one $x \in M$

$\text{dist}(z,M):=\inf\{d(x,y):y\in M\}$

I supposed that there are two points $x_1,x_2\in M$ which satisfy $\|x-z\|=dist(z,M)$. Then I know that also $x_1t+x_2(1-t)\in M$ But that doesn't help. I am struggling in how to use the property of X given above.

Any Ideas? Please **don't** post full solutions, only tipps please. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Use $t = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Well, then $\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\in M$ . But the norms of $x_1$ and $x_2$ are not necessairly 1. Should I consider $\frac{x_1}{||x_1||}$ and $\frac{x_2}{||x_2]]}$? Does this go into the right direction? I guess at the end we will get a contradiction because the will be a smaller distance between z and M. Correct?

Comment: That's right, the mid-point between $x_1$ and $x_2$ will turn out to be strictly nearer to $z$. But note that the norms of $x_1$ and $x_2$ are irrelevant, since we don't apply the given condition to those. From the given condition, can you deduce a condition on $u$ and $v$ so that you have $$\left\lVert \tfrac{1}{2}(u+v)\right\rVert < \tfrac{1}{2}\left(\lVert u\rVert + \lVert v\rVert\right)\,?$$ And then can you see that the relevant vectors here satisfy that condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We now that, if $\|u\|=\|v\|$ and $u\ne v$, then $\big\|\frac{1}{2}(u+v)\big\|<\frac{1}{2}\|u\|+\frac{1}{2}\|v\|$.  To understand this, let $u_1=u/\|u\|$, $v_1=v/\|v\|$, then $\|u_1\|=\|v_1\|=1$, and as $u_1\ne v_1$, 
$$
\bigg\|\frac{1}{2}(u+v)\bigg\|=\bigg\|\frac{1}{2}\|u\|(u_1+v_1)\bigg\|
=\|u\|\bigg\|\frac{1}{2}(u_1+v_1)\bigg\| \\ 
<\frac{1}{2}\|u\|(\|u_1\|+\|v_1\|)=\frac{1}{2}(\|u\|+\|v\|).
$$

Now, if
$$
\|x_1-z\|=\mathrm{dist}(z,M)\quad\text{and}\quad \|x_2-z\|=\mathrm{dist}(z,M)
$$
then for $u=x_1-z$ and $v=x_2-z$, we obtain:
$$
\big\|\tfrac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2)-z\big\|=\big\|\tfrac{1}{2}\big((x_1-z)+(x_2-z)\big)\big\|<
\frac{1}{2}\big(\|x_1-z\|+\|x_2-z\|\big),
$$
and as $\tfrac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2)\in M$, we reach to a contradicition.

Comment: So in the inequality you just use the triangle inequality? We dont need our inequality assumption given in the question above?

Comment: Actually, I had to fix my answer. See the updated version, where the assumption is indeed used.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand it, since $||x||,||y||$ must have norm 1. How you got the first line in your post?

Comment: See my explanation in my edited answer.

Comment: I still don't understand it, since after the inequality there should be a "1", because $\frac{1}{2}(||u_1||+||v_1||)<1$

Comment: If in the inequality you take away $\|u\|$ then the right-hand side is equal to 1 - think!